# Jquery datepicker to show multiple color on date selection

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a date picker which shows active days. Within these active days, I need to show different color on selecting each date instead of date picker's default color. 
I have three array of dates which determines which color to show.

```
array1 = {8/5/2013, 8/14/2013, 8/21/2013} - Background Blue
array2 = {8/15/2013, 8/22/2013} - Background Red 
array3 = {8/9/2013, 8/13/2013} - Background Green
```

How can I extend the date picker to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Like this: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VgekG/)**

```
$('#dp').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: colorize
});
var blueDates = ['8-5-2013', '8-14-2013', '8-21-2013'];
var greenDates = ['8-15-2013', '8-22-2013'];
var redDates = ['8-9-2013', '8-13-2013'];
function colorize(date) {
    mdy = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear();
    console.log(mdy);
    if ($.inArray(mdy, blueDates) > -1) {
        return [true, "blue"];
    } else if ($.inArray(mdy, greenDates) > -1) {
        return [true, "green"];
    } else if ($.inArray(mdy, redDates) > -1) {
        return [true, "red"];
    } else {
        return [true, ""];
    }
}
```

Comment: My calendar is an inline multiple datepicker and i need to show these colors while clicking on the date cell.